# Creating copy of class instance with randomly init variable (python)

Tags: python, random

I need to initialize an instance of a class with a randomly generated number.  I then need to use this instance in several different trials.  However, I am having troubles making exact copies of this instance - the randomly generated number will not stay the same.  Each copy is generating a new random number.

```
temp = proc(random.randint(min, max))
tempCpy = copy.copy(temp) #changes on temp interfere with tempCpy
tempCpy = copy.deepcopy(temp)  #doesn't start with same random number
```

Comment: We need more code for your object's class and whatnot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class something like this, I assume:

```
class proc(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

And when you initialize your first instance, you write:

```
temp = proc(random.randint(min, max))
```

And this stores the random number in `temp.value`.

To make a copy, you can just pass in `temp.value` to the `proc` constructor:

```
dupe = proc(temp.value)
```

You could also write your class to do this automatically, so that when you pass an instance of `proc` to the `proc` constructor, it makes a copy (as with other types, such as `list` and `dict`, whose constructors can be used to make copies of them). This has the advantage of keeping all the knowledge of what needs to be done to make copies *in the class* instead of the caller needing to know where the data is stored.

```
class proc(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, proc):
            value = value.value
        self.value = value
```

Now, you can write:

```
dupe = proc(temp)
```

A related method is to write an alternate constructor (often named `from`) as a classmethod on the class.

```
class proc(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def from(cls, other):
        return cls(other.value)
```

Copying is then:

```
dupe = proc.from(temp)
```

Alternatively, you could add a method to `proc` to make the copy:

```
class proc(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def copy(self):
        return type(self)(self.value)
```

Now your copy is:

```
dupe = temp.copy()
```

Finally, if you name your `copy` method `__copy__` instead (or use both names), *it will magically work with `copy.copy`!*

```
class proc(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def copy(self):
        return type(self)(self.value)

    __copy__ = copy   # alias for use by 'copy' module

temp = proc(random.randint(min, max))
dupe = copy.copy(temp)
```

Comment: This is probably the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize random.seed() with an argument you will reuse. It will guarantee that you generate "the same random number". (e.g. random.seed(0) before the rest of your code)

Comment: Other answer probably answered the asked question better, but this is exactly what I needed to use.  Thanks

Comment: Why not make it the accepted answer if it was what you needed, then?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can just make random number separatly from your object?

```
init_numb = random.randint(min, max)
temp = proc(init_numb)
tempCpy = copy.copy(temp) #changes on temp interfere with tempCpy
tempCpy = copy.deepcopy(temp)
```